Remove uikit components from gradle in compose multiplatform app running on windows
Running a compose multiplatform app on windows, is there a way to stop gradle from downloading all the uikit components, since they won't be used anyways.
Padding to make stackoverflow happy
Gradle disables running of apple components on windows platform

